# Newman CLI on Gitlab ECONNECT issue

Tags: gitlab, postman, newman

I have a CI/CD pipeline which uses gitlab runners, the docker image that i am using for the pipeline is node v12. The node server runs as a daemon process on port 3000. I am using newman CLI to test my postman collection of APIs after the server is started.

Newman CLI is not able to connect to the node server which is running (which i know for sure is running from the logs) and i get the following error:

`ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000`

Any ideas on what i could be doing wrong?

Comment: does docker have access to loaclhost? did you set up that route ?

Comment: I did not specifically set that up, how can i setup that route ?

Comment: is server running in container or in localhost of the host ?

Comment: the server is running in the docker container

Comment: create a network and add both the docker in the same network

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/

Comment: else the containers cannot see eachother

Comment: but what i dont understand is that the node server is running in the container and as a daemon process so the newman cli should be able to access the APIs since its also part of the same container, there is no separate container

Comment: ho ok i thought you are running newman from a separate container than the server process spawn .

Comment: can you just add a ping test and see if the server is accessible while newman runs

Comment: i tried curling from the docker and it gave the same error

Comment: So it's not running , how did you verify it's running .

Comment: from the pm2 logs,  i can see that the server process is started

Comment: @PDHide the issue seemed to be the timing of newman CLI running and the server being started, i added a dumb command between these steps and newman can make the connection now to the server